# Reusing a docsis 2.0 modem

Tags: modem, video-streaming, cable-modem

Comcast recently refused to activate an old docsis 2.0 modem that I had with me. I am wondering if it could be put to any use. One idea I had was to connect it to a TV through the coax, and stream video in over ethernet. Is this even possible? Maybe there is a firmware update to make it work? If this is beyond hope,are there any suggested uses for my modem? I really don't want to just throw it away..

Comment: Most modems firmware is closed source.  Such an old modem in 2015 does not hold any value.

Comment: Chuck it in the trash.